# Displaying tooltips during mousedrag

Tags: c++, windows, tooltip

I'd like to display a tooltip while a user is dragging a mouse to create a rectangle.  The contents of the tooltip would be an indication of the size of the rectangle.  I don't know how to get the tooltip to display when the mouse button is down, and to stop displaying when the mouse button is up.

The application is written in C++ on Windows, using Visual Studio 2005, no MFC, no ATL.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a [`TTM_ACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760326(v=vs.85).aspx) message to turn the tooltip window on or off.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, but that didn't do it.  More specifically, I'm running XP,

Comment: @abfinger, does your window have a tooltip window associated with it? I know MFC provides one automatically, but you're not using MFC...